# removing and adding classes in button set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this set of buttons:

```
<div class="test-button-set">
  <button id="hdfs_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HDFS</button>
  <button id="hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE</button>
  <button id="hdfs_hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, when I click on one of these buttons, add a class to the clicked button and remove the same class from all the other buttons. This is what I have so far but as I am new to JS/jQuery I am having a bit of trouble

```
var testButtonSet = document.getElementsByClassName("test-button-set")[0].getElementsByTagName("button");
testButtonSet.forEach($(this).click(function() {
    testButtonSet.removeClass("selected");
    this.addClass("selected");
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be:

```
$( '.test-button-set button' ).click(function() {
    $( '.test-button-set button' ).removeClass("selected");
    $( this ).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Close. You're trying to use jQuery methods on raw-DOM objects. Wrap them first:

```
testButtonSet.forEach($(this).click(function() {
    $(testButtonSet).removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
}));
```

Or, to go full-jQuery:

```
var testButtons = $('.test-button-set button');

testButtons.click( function() {
  testButtons.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected'); 
});
```

Example:

```js
var testButtons = $('.test-button-set button');

testButtons.click(function() {
  testButtons.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-button-set">
  <button id="hdfs_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HDFS</button>
  <button id="hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">HIVE</button>
  <button id="hdfs_hive_test" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">BOTH</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The pure jQuery way would be:

```
$('.test-button-set button').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings().removeClass("selected");
    $this.addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the foreach function receives a function as a first parameter so instead of using it like this:

```
testButtonSet.forEach($(this).click(function() {
    testButtonSet.removeClass("selected");
    this.addClass("selected");
}));
```

It should be used like this:

```
testButtonSet.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    $(element).click(function() {
        testButtonSet.removeClass("selected");
        this.addClass("selected");
    })
);
```

However the foreach method works with arrays and not dom elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Fortunately we have a couple of things to work around this...

One is to "demethodize" it as shown here:

```
var each = Function.prototype.call.bind([].forEach);
```

http://colintoh.com/blog/5-array-methods-that-you-should-use-today#demethodizing

Another one is to use jquery "each" method i.e.

```
$.each(array, function(){});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
$(elements).each(function(){});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

That being said, now you can choose between using jquery or the native demethodized version.

```
each(testButtonSet, function(element, index, array){
    $(element).click(function() {
        testButtonSet.removeClass("selected");
        this.addClass("selected");
    });
}); 

$(testButtonSet).each(function(index, element){
    $(element).click(function() {
        testButtonSet.removeClass("selected");
        this.addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Fiddles:
forEach: http://jsfiddle.net/ze6bkprg/
Jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/n8sn9y2k/